# Grid is not getting binded properly in IE

Tags: asp.net

My grid is not binding properly in IE and I found the reson why it is not working.
One of my column values in my grid is showing video and database value is:

```
<object id='video' width='462' height='407'  type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'>   <param name='movie' value='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'>   <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'>    <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>    <param name='wmode' value='transparent'>    <param name='flashvars' value='colourSet=blue&brandText=LSAT+Freedom&brandLink=lsatfreedom.com'>    <embed src='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'
```

When I add a comment to this column while binding, my grid is working fine and showing all next records.

But I want this column.

How do I bind  tag to grid so that a video can be displayed?
I have tried this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblAns" runat ="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%>'></asp:Literal>
```

and

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%>
```

and

```
<asp:Label ID="lblAns" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%>'></asp:Label>
```

but it is not working.

Please tell me how to bind this.

Comment: can't get it.. you have a table in which you have video in binary format??? do you want a embed video player in grid row to play that video??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using TemplateField (GridView) or TemplateColumn (DataGrid), you should replicate the mark-up to be generated and use data binding expressions in place if dynamic text. For example,

```
<asp:templatefield>

  <itemtemplate>
     <div>
      <object id="video" width="462" height="407"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         data='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UrlToVideo")%>'>
         <param name="movie" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UrlToVideo")%>'>
         ...
     </div>
  </itemtemplate>

</asp:templatefield>
```

Replace "UrlToVideo" by the actual column/property name from data source that will contain the link to the video.